# How to execute a string by replacing a comma with single quote comma single quote in IN SQL query

Tags: sql

```
Select ((REPLACE ('963,654' , ','  , ''',''') ) ) from Dummytable
```

I am able to execute above query But when i am writing the same replace condition in IN query i am not able to execute

Select * from Dummytable WHERE '963' IN (''''|| (REPLACE ( '963, 654' , ','  , ''',''') ) || '''')

Comment: Best would be to first split all the values and insert them into temp table, once you do that you can easily join that table on DummyTable and get your results

Comment: Thanks for the comment, is there any alternative without inserting into a new table . and also want to know why its not executing in IN query when it is executing in other queries.

Comment: Because 963 is not in your replace query .... to be IN your results it has to be same ... so better go with LIKE 
Select * from DummyTable
where ((REPLACE ([Text] , ','  , ''',''') ) ) LIKE  '%' +  '963' + '%'

Comment: it is working when i write like this   select * from dual WHERE '963' IN ('963',' 654')

Answer (score 0):

it is becuase of this

```
Select * from Dummytable WHERE '963' IN (''''|| (REPLACE ( '963, 654' , ',' , ''',''') ) || '''')
```

becomes

```
Select * from Dummytable WHERE '963' IN (''''|| '963'','' 654'  || '''')
```

which becomes

```
Select * from Dummytable WHERE '963' IN ('''963'','' 654''')
```

your problems is `'''963'','' 654'''` is a single string.. not a list of strings